# Scaled trace theorem for $H(div)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

The scaled trace theorem is well known, i.e. there holds
\begin{align*}
\|v\|_{L^2(\partial K)} \leq C \left(h_k^{1/2} \|\nabla  v\|_{L^2(K)} + h_k^{-1/2}\|v\|_{L^2(K)}\right) \quad \forall v\in H^1(K).
\end{align*}
where $h_k$ denotes the diameter of the open domain $K$ with Lipschitz-boundary $\partial K$. I am looking for a similar result which holds for $H(\text{div}, K)$-functions. For example something like
\begin{align*}
\|\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}\|_{L^2(\partial K)} \leq C \left(h_k^{1/2} \|\text{div}(\mathbf{v})\|_{L^2(K)} + h_k^{-1/2}\|\mathbf{v}\|_{L^2(K)}\right) \quad \forall v\in H(\text{div},K).
\end{align*}
Can you give me a reference on this? Thanks a lot.